# Amazon RDS Upgrade

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We have a RDS service having MultiAZ setup with Database mirroring on. We are looking for upgrading it to higher instance type. How to do that and if someone can point me to a best practice with steps to do that and what should we take care of so as to not corrupt or destroy the data ?

Comment: You can go through this doc: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/scaling-your-amazon-rds-instance-vertically-and-horizontally/. Since you've Multi-AZ enabled the downtime should be minimal.